# PrestaShop Theme Bug

Tags: templates, themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have freshly installed PrestaShop 1.6.12 and I install PTS Basic Theme from there: [PrestaBrain](http://www.prestabrain.com/theme/pts-basic/)  (developer says it's working on 1.6.X versions). 
I installed all modules and switched for this theme. 
On my website i can see just this:

[image]

Error says: No template found for module pspagebuilder. I sent question how to slove this to developer of this theme but i didn't get any answer.

How to fix it? Also maybe should I downgrade my Presta to lower version? Maybe 1.6.11 (how to do that?). I can't find any solution in google.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a reply on your question on PrestaBrain Ticksy :

https://prestabrain.ticksy.com/ticket/1141690/

> hi, you can download it in here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8klnq2hmljoqb9/pf_basic_full.zip?dl=0
>
> we update module pspagebuilder, psverticalmenu
>
> thanks